# How to load file.ml

Tags: file, ocaml

How to load a file myfile.ml that I can use it my file?
And where should I put this file for the compiler to find it?

Answer (score 29):

You don't say what kind of system you're using. It's also not clear whether you're trying to load code into the toplevel (the interpreter), use external functions from an OCaml program or something else. It would help if you explained more carefully.

In the meantime, here's a session with a Unix-like system (Mac OS X) that shows how to load a file into the toplevel:

```
$ cat myfile.ml
let f x = x + 1
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# #use "myfile.ml";;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# f 14;;
- : int = 15
#
```

For this purpose, it doesn't matter too much where your file is. You just need to specify its name in the `#use` directive. If you don't know how to specify a filename, that's not an OCaml problem--and it's probably the first thing you need to figure out :-)

Answer (score 12):

in your command line, type `ocaml` or `utop`, then `#use 'yourfile.ml'`

I suggest you read [Real World Ocaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/) and learn.

Comment: where should be this file ?

Comment: whereever you call utop or ocaml

Comment: ... or wherever you want and specify the full or relative path.

Comment: For `utop` at least, the command should be `#use "myfile.ml"`

Answer (score 11):

you can also run utop with the -init option:

```
utop -init yourfile.ml
```